# C# OnclientClick doens't render asp tags?

Tags: c#, onclientclick

I have an ASP button that lookts like this:

```
<asp:Button 
  ID="btnReset" 
  runat="server" 
  OnClientClick = "hideOverlay('<%=pnlOverlay.ClientID %>', '<%=pnlAddComment.ClientID  %>');"
  CssClass ="btnCancel PopUpButton"
/>
```

The problem are the asp tags in de hideOverlay part.I don't get it working. Why isn't working? And how do i fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below examples

First Example

In aspx

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnReset" runat="server" CssClass="btnCancel PopUpButton" />
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlOverlay" runat="server">
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlAddComment" runat="server">
        </asp:Panel>        
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In Codebehind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default10 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       btnReset.Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format("hideOverlay('{0}','{1}')", pnlOverlay.ClientID, pnlAddComment.ClientID));

    }
}
```

It will generate the below source for the button

```
<input type="submit" name="btnReset" value="" onclick="hideOverlay('pnlOverlay','pnlAddComment');" id="btnReset" class="btnCancel PopUpButton" />
```

Second Example

In Aspx

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnReset" runat="server" CssClass="btnCancel PopUpButton" OnClientClick=<%# "hideOverlay('" + pnlOverlay.ClientID + "', '" + pnlAddComment.ClientID +"');" %> />
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlOverlay" runat="server">
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlAddComment" runat="server">
        </asp:Panel>        
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In CodeBehind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default10 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnReset.DataBind(); 
    }
}
```

It will generate the below source for the button

```
<input type="submit" name="btnReset" value="" onclick="hideOverlay('pnlOverlay', 'pnlAddComment');" id="btnReset" class="btnCancel PopUpButton" />
```

Third Example

In aspx

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnReset" runat="server" CssClass="btnCancel PopUpButton" OnClientClick="hideOverlay();" />
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlOverlay" runat="server">
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlAddComment" runat="server">
        </asp:Panel>        
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function hideOverlay()
    {
        var pnlOverlayID = '<%= pnlOverlay.ClientID %>';
        var pnlAddCommentID = '<%= pnlAddComment.ClientID %>';

        //Do your stuff
    }
</script> 
</html>
```

It will generate the follwing source for the script portion

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function hideOverlay()
    {
        var pnlOverlayID = 'pnlOverlay';
        var pnlAddCommentID = 'pnlAddComment';

        //Do your stuff
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace "=" with "#" in you inline code. e.g. **<%=pnlOverlay.ClientID %>** => **<%#pnlOverlay.ClientID %>**, so that the **ClientId** is instantiated in compile time.

[OnClientClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx) is only used to call client-sidee script such as javascript code. If you are trying to call a method in code behind, you should use **OnClick** event.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
<asp:Button 
  ID="btnReset" 
  runat="server" 
  OnClientClick=<%# "hideOverlay('" + pnlOverlay.ClientID + "', '" + pnlAddComment.ClientID +"');" %>
  CssClass ="btnCancel PopUpButton"
/>
```

or even nicer if you use `string.Format()`

```
OnClientClick=<%# string.Format("hideOverlay('{0}', '{1}');", pnlOverlay.ClientID,pnlAddComment.ClientID) %>
```

And don't forget to databind the link, and yes the `onclientclick` doesn't have `"` , since those are used inside the `<%# %>` tags

Comment: I've tried your code, but it doesn't work. When i look at the source i see:
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$cphContent$btnReset" value="" id="ctl00_cphContent_btnReset" class="btnCancel PopUpButton" />

The onclick attribute is gone, how come?. And what do you mean with the databind link?

Comment: In your codebehind you have to call "DataBind();" or "btnReset.DataBind()"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

i. In the code behind

```
btnReset.OnClientClick = "hideOverlay'"+pnlOverlay.ClientID+"','"+pnlAddComment.ClientID+"')";
```

ii. The second approach is to use an inline javascript.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnReset" runat="server" OnClientClick = "newhideOverlay()" CssClass
="btnCancel PopUpButton"/>

<script type="text/javascript">

function newhideOverlay() 

{    
      hideOverlay('<%=pnlOverlay.ClientID %>', '<%=pnlAddComment.ClientID  %>');

} 

</script>
```

Also ensure that both pnlOverlay and pnlAddComment load before the button.